# Handling of special characters in popover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, special-characters, popover

I had a web application built in jQuery, html, bootstrap. Recently I had a requirement of showing special characters in screens. Since the data is received via services in XML, I had to make a special handling for "<" , ">". Now from service I am passing `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead.

In UI, the values in `<span>` are filled correctly as HTML can manipulate these characters accordingly. But on a popover, the values are still coming as `&lt;`

Suppose if my service response was `Saura&lt;bh`. This is shown as `Saura<bh` on screens (which is as required) but on popover it still appears as `Saura&lt;bh`.

I went through a similar question on SO (the only one that I could find), but the solution doesn't work.

Can someone provide me how to handle this case.

EDIT: Adding code for reference:

```
<div class="port-slot">
        <span class="port-sublabel jCommodity" rel="popover" data-placement="left" data-original-title=""></span></br>
        <span class="port-label"><span class="jContType"></span></span>
      </div>


if (!bookingBlDetails.data.isMultipleCommodities) {
                    jQuery($console).find('.jCommodityItems').html(bookingBlDetails.data.commodityDesc);
                    $(".jCommodityItems").attr('data-content', jQuery($console).find(".jCommodityItems").html());
                    if (jQuery($console).find(".jCommodityItems").html().length > 24) {
                        jQuery($console).find(".jCommodityItems").html(jQuery($console).find(".jCommodityItems").html().substring(0, 24) + _elipses);
                    }
                } else {
                    jQuery($console).find('.jCommodityItems').html(Messages["multipleCommodities"]);
                }
                popoverTrigger(['jCommodityItems']);
```

As can be seen, I had a popover to show data and a limit of 24 characters to be shown in it before ellipsing. This popover is not showing handled characters while the other span shows

Comment: Could you please provide a working example like fiddle or plunker

Comment: That simply depends on how you're handling the data/popover. More code please.

Comment: Added code for refernece..please have a look again

Comment: append sura and bt in quote or double qoute with +

Comment: Isn't there a general way of handling it. As I will never know at which location special character might appear. Though I can check for it and split it accordingly. But that's not possible always because I will have to split for letters that appears in beginning of many character